# Java board array trouble

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I am working on a program to create a battleship game using ansi codes. The ansi codes isn't much of a problem, since I found out that these codes allow me to overwrite print lines. My plan was to use this to place ships on a already drawn board. My problem lies in my array that's placing the ships ("0"). Can't seem to get past the nullpointerexception error. I feel that this is the only thing stopping me from finishing the program. Any help would be highly appreciated.

A portion of my program is below.

Coordinate Class :

```
public class Coordinate {
   public String piece;
   int row, col, type;
   public boolean select, empty, hit, ship;
   public String [][] shipPiece;

   public String section()
   {
       piece = "i";

       empty = true;
       select = false;
       hit = false;
       //ship = false;

       if (empty)
       {
           piece = "\033[33m0\033[0m";
       }
       else if(!empty)
       {
           //empty = true;
           ship = true;
           piece = "0";
       }
       else if(!hit && ship)
           piece = "\033[33m0\033[0m";

       return piece;
   }

   public String placeShip()
   {
       for(int x = 0; x<=10; x++)
       {
           for(int y = 0; y<=10; y++)
           {
               shipPiece[x][y] = piece;
           }
       }
       return piece;   
   }
}
```

Player class :

```
public class Player {

    private String name1, name2;
    //private ArrayList<Coordinate> moves;
    //private Coordinate move;
    private int playerNumber;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Board bawd = new Board();
    Coordinate c = new Coordinate();
    Ship sh = new Ship();

    public Player(){}

    public void GetNames()
    {
        for(playerNumber = 1; playerNumber <= 2; playerNumber++)
        {
           System.out.print("Player " + playerNumber + ": ");
           name1 = in.nextLine();
           playerNumber++;
           System.out.print("Player " + playerNumber + ": ");
           name2 = in.nextLine();
           System.out.print("\033[2J");
        }
    }

    public void setShips()
    {
        bawd.singleP1View();
        sh.coordLoc();
        System.out.println("\033[2J");
        bawd.singleP2View();
        sh.coordLoc();
        System.out.println("\033[2J");
        game();
    }

    public void game()
    {
        bawd.p1turn();
        c.placeShip();
    }

}
```

Comment: On what line is your null pointer exception occurring?

Comment: line 41 of the Coordinate class

Comment: Yeah, that clears it right up.

Comment: Coolness!! but now it gives me the usual arrayoutofbounds :(

Comment: Small question, if the output is giving me a random memory offset (ie. [[Ljava.lang.String;@b988a6), I am suppose to make a toString method correct? if so, how would I approach that?

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Second thoughts, no you shouldn't.  It'll probably get closed.  Go and read up on `toString` methods.

Comment: Yeah, I started doing that lol. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `shipPiece array` is not initialized.

Change

```
 public String [][] shipPiece;
```

to

```
 public String [][] shipPiece = new String [11][11];
```

Comment: Alrighty that seemed to fix the problems, thanks David and Prabs :)

Answer (score 0):

This has never been initialized

```
public String [][] shipPiece;
```

You should initialize something like this

```
public String [][] shipPiece = new String[10][10];
```

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize your `shipPiece`. You have to initialize it for example this way:

```
public String [][] shipPiece = new String[11][11];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String [][] shipPiece;
```

You are not initializing this bad boy !!!